# Access slug url without clicking Link not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Suspect I am having a getStatisProps, getStaticPaths related problem in Nextjs. When I click the link from index.js the page loads fine... However when I access the slug url directly by for example pasting http://www.localhost:3000/casinos/casino-x into the url field of web browser it does not work and **context.params.slug becomes undefined**....

**Question 1:**  How do I get around that?

**Question 2:**  How do I preload all my casino urls in getStaticPaths, at the moment I only use one url for fallback ({ slug: "mr-vegas-casino").

**Page 1: (index.js)**

```
<Link href={`/casinos/${casino.slug}`}><a className={featured.link}>Read Review</a></Link>
```

**Page 2:** **( casinos/[slug].js )**

```
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { API_URL } from "@/config/index";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  inMemoryCache,
  gql,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import router from "next/router";


export default function CasinoPage({ casinos }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={containers.outerContainer}>

      <div className={containers.whiteSection}>
        <SecondSection casinos={casinos} />
      </div>

    .........

      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { slug: "mr-vegas-casino" } }],
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const slug = context.params.slug
  console.log(slug)

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:1337/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });


  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query Casinos($slug: String) {
        casinos(where: { slug: $slug }) {
          slug
          name
          logo {
            url
          }
          rating
          owner
          founded
          payout_percentage
          bonuses {
            name
            slug
            title
            cashable
            bonus_type{
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      slug
    }
  });

  return {
    props: {
      casinos: data.casinos[0],
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Please show your dynamic route definitions: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: is this happening in development environment or after deploy in vercel ?

Comment: if local, then i think this is expected. as next js would generate the dynamic page only when you click the link. if you type the url in browser, then the page should be generated already and available, which happens only in prod

Comment: Using `fallback: true` should ensure new pages would be generated no matter how they're accessed. I'm not able to replicate the issue, could you provide a codesandbox or similar with the issue?